# Extending mysqli - Overload execute()

Tags: php, mysqli

I have extended the MySQLi class like so:

```
class my_mysqli extends MySQLi
{
public $queries = 0;

function __construct($host = '', $user = '', $pass = '', $db = '')
{
    if (is_object($host) or $host == '')
    {
        parent::__construct(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);

        if ($this->connect_error)
        {
            my_error('Cannot connect to MySQL server: ' . $this->connect_error);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    }
}

public function prepare($query)
{
    $p = parent::prepare($query);

    $this->check_error();

    return $p;
}

public function execute()
{
    $this->queries++;

    parent::execute();
}

public function query($query)
{
    $p = parent::query ($query);

    $this->check_error();

    $this->queries++;

    return $p;
}

public function check_error()
{
    if ($this->error)
    {
        my_error($this->error, true);
    }
}

}
```

The problem is, nothing is happening with execute().  What must I do to overload this method?  Right now, it gets ignored.  According to the php.net site, there is no argument needed for the execute method.  At a bit of a loss.

Comment: Isn't `execute` a method of `mysqli_stmt`? Seeing as you aren't extending that, I doubt you're going to see anything happen there. Extending the built-in PHP database classes is generally a pretty bad idea.

Comment: I guess I am looking at it here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Is that not part of MySQLi?